# JavaFx and Jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

This is a car rental system. I wrote this using JavaFX and JDBC. I created this with a layered architecture.

"An error occurred: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatment(String)" because "connection" is null. "

This is the error I get in my application.

This is my DbConnection class.

```
package lk.ijse.carrentalsystem.db;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DbConnection {
    private static DbConnection dbConnection;
    private static Connection connection;

    private DbConnection(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Supermarket", "root", "Xhq8nc3mcj");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static DbConnection getInstance(){
        if (dbConnection == null){
            dbConnection = new DbConnection();
        }
        return dbConnection;
    }

    public static Connection getConnection(){
        return connection;
    }
}
```

This is my CustomerDaoImpl class

```
import com.mysql.cj.Session;
import lk.ijse.carrentalsystem.dao.custom.CustomerDao;
import lk.ijse.carrentalsystem.db.DbConnection;
import lk.ijse.carrentalsystem.entity.CustomerEntity;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao {

    @Override
    public boolean addCustomer(CustomerEntity entity) throws Exception {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO customer (custTitle, custName, custNic, address, mobile) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        try (Connection connection = DbConnection.getConnection()) {
            try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {

                // Set values in the prepared statement
                preparedStatement.setString(1, entity.getCustTitle());
                preparedStatement.setString(2, entity.getCustName());
                preparedStatement.setString(3, entity.getCustNic());
                preparedStatement.setString(4, entity.getAddress());
                preparedStatement.setString(5, entity.getMobile());

                // Execute the SQL query
                int rowsAffected = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                // Check if the insertion was successful
                return rowsAffected > 0;

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // Handle any SQL exceptions
                e.printStackTrace(); // You can log the exception or handle it in a better way
            }

            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Terrible, misleading title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 2):

From the way you have defined a `public static DbConnection static getInstance()`method, it looks like you are attempting to implement a singleton pattern.

First, you should note that many (I would say most) programmers consider the singleton to be an anti-pattern  and generally be bad practice. I would strongly recommend against using this approach. (I would certainly not tolerate it from anyone I supervise.) Use some kind of dependency injection instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-are-drawbacks-or-disadvantages-of-singleton-pattern), for example, or many other resources.

The issue is that you call the static `DbConnection.getConnection()` method which returns the static `connection` object. This is only initialized via `DbConnection.getInstance()`, which you never call, so it is null.

If you do insist on using this approach (and for learning purposes it does provide some simplicity), then the `connection` field should not be `static`; it should be an instance field that belongs to the (one and only) `DbConnection` instance.

So:

```
public class DbConnection {
    private static DbConnection dbConnection;

    // not static:
    private Connection connection;

    private DbConnection(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Supermarket", "root", "Xhq8nc3mcj");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static DbConnection getInstance(){
        if (dbConnection == null){
            dbConnection = new DbConnection();
        }
        return dbConnection;
    }

    // not static:
    public Connection getConnection(){
        return connection;
    }
}
```

and then in your application code you do

```
Connection connection = DbConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
```

or

```
DbConnection dbConnection = DbConnection.getInstance();

// ...

Connection connection = dbConnection.getConnection();
```